# facing issue with aggregate not working in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am working with mongodb shell

I created a two database

first database with first table

```
> use post                                       --created a new database
switched to db post
> db.post.find().pretty()                        --created a new table
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f22e79cbb26262249d35bc"),
        "title" : "my first post",
        "author" : "Jim",
        "likes" : 5
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f22e79cbb26262249d35bd"),
        "title" : "my second post",
        "author" : "Jim",
        "likes" : 2
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f22e79cbb26262249d35be"),
        "title" : "hello world",
        "author" : "Joe",
        "likes" : 3
}
```

second database with second table

```
> use comment                                  --created a new database
switched to db comment
> db.comment.find().pretty()                   --created a new table
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f2308dcbb26262249d35bf"),
        "postTitle" : "my first post",
        "comment" : "great read",
        "likes" : 3
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f2308dcbb26262249d35c0"),
        "postTitle" : "my second post",
        "comment" : "good info",
        "likes" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f2308dcbb26262249d35c1"),
        "postTitle" : "my second post",
        "comment" : "i liked this post",
        "likes" : 12
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f2308dcbb26262249d35c2"),
        "postTitle" : "hello world",
        "comment" : "not my favorite",
        "likes" : 8
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("61f2308dcbb26262249d35c3"),
        "postTitle" : "my last post",
        "comment" : null,
        "likes" : 0
}
```

my query:

```
> use post
switched to db post
> db.post.aggregate([{ $lookup:{from: "comment",localField: "postTitle",foreignField: "title",as: "data"}} ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f22e79cbb26262249d35bc"), "title" : "my first post", "author" : "Jim", "likes" : 5, "data" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f22e79cbb26262249d35bd"), "title" : "my second post", "author" : "Jim", "likes" : 2, "data" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("61f22e79cbb26262249d35be"), "title" : "hello world", "author" : "Joe", "likes" : 3, "data" : [ ] }
```

**showing the "data" : [] is empty**

[image]

data[] is showing empty I am trying and trying but data[] is showing empty

I am following the document but not showing the data[]

need help

Comment: @R2D2 not working thanks for answer

Comment: just tested , yours seems to work as expected: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vd2dvR01DZT

Comment: @R2D2 ERROR is ```db.post.aggregate is not a function :```

Comment: ah just saw a small detail , you are doing lookup between two databases, then the query differ abit , the from need to be from: {db: <db>, coll: <collection-to-join>}

Comment: @R2D2 trying and trying but not working please help ```> db.post.aggregate([{"$lookup":{"from": "comment","localField": "post.title","foreignField": "comment.postTitle","as": "data"}}]);```

Comment: @R2D2 error is ReferenceError: getSiblingDb is not defined :

Comment: In that case remove it and use the main db

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct query for lookup between collections in different databases:

```
use post
db post.aggregate([{ 
      $lookup:{
         from:{
              db:"comment",coll:"comment"
              },
           localField: "postTitle",
           foreignField: "title",
           as: "data"
             }} 
          ])
```

[reference to mongoDB docs lookup example](https://docs.mongodb.com/datalake/reference/pipeline/lookup-stage/)